# dates in swift - daily to weekly

Tags: swift, date

Please help with dates in Swift 3. What I try to do is:
1. get first element in array of Date; if it's not Monday then set this Date to Monday; get next Monday's Date.
2. make a loop: while *next element* is related to current week then ... (perform smth)

```
    func d2w(daily: [Date], data: [Double]) -> ([Date], [Double]) {
        var weekly = [Date]()
        var wdata = [Double]()

        var calendar = Calendar.current
        var wday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: daily[0]) - calendar.firstWeekday
        //if wday != 1 { ... }
        //any other solution with Sunday is the first day of week?

        //while daily == *current week { wdata += data }
        //weekly.append()
        return (weekly, wdata)
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Exactly what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to convert daily OHLC data to weekly OHLC.
O = open value of 1 day of week; C = close value of last day of the week; H - max value, L - min value; and to assign Monday's date of the week to this OHLC value

Comment: So you want to find the OHCL weekly data from last monday to coming monday?

Comment: from monday to friday, 5 days (or can be less). But Monday is assigned to OHLC even if it was not a working day